# Error in Internet Explorer 9  (not earlier versions or other browsers) when including jQuery in an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

Basically I have a page that launched a fancybox iframe. In that iframe I also include jQuery. But when I testing it in Internet Explorer 9 it gives me the error

> Line: 68\n Error: 'Object' is undefined`

This error is in file `jquery-1.4.1.js` and the line in question is the second line of this:

```
// Save a reference to some core methods
toString = Object.prototype.toString,
hasOwnProperty = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,
push = Array.prototype.push,
slice = Array.prototype.slice,
indexOf = Array.prototype.indexOf;
```

which is the last lines of the `var jQuery = function( selector, context ) {`.

No problem if I'm in compatibility view, no problem in any other browsers, just Internet Explorer 9 in Internet Explorer 9 mode and Internet Explorer 9 standards. If I ignore the error I see no problems using any version of jQuery.

What's up, and what I can do to fix?

Comment: Update jQuery to the latest version

Comment: updated jquery to 1.6.1, now the error is on line 81, same `toString = Object.prototype.toString` code though.

Comment: Does it happen when you open the content of the iframe directly?  That is, if you just open the iframe page by itself?

Comment: @jimbojw: No sir, the code in the iframe runs error free if loaded in it's own window.

Comment: I'd be curious whether the iframe is being created before or after the src attribute is set.  If the iframe is created, and /then/ the src attribute is set, it could be a problem.  (As opposed to building an HTML string containing <iframe src="blah"/> and injecting it wholesale into an element with innerHTML).

Comment: @jimbojw: I really don't know and would have to dig into the fancybox code, I found a work around by going to compatibility view and can't really take the time to dig through their code. It's open source though so anyone should be able to root around in there and find out.

Comment: Sounds like your best bet may be to file a bug report with the fancybox maintainers.

Comment: Thanks jimbojw, I went ahead and did that.

Comment: Ah too bad you did not paste the issue tracker URL for us to follow up on this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D'oh, thought I had the latest fancy box. Turns out I had 1.3.1, 1.3.4 fixes this issue.

**UPD(sompylasar):** In fact, that was fixed in 1.3.2 (see the [changelog](http://fancybox.net/changelog/)). I've compared the [source code of 1.3.2](http://code.google.com/p/fancybox/downloads/detail?name=jquery.fancybox-1.3.2.zip) with [1.3.1](http://code.google.com/p/fancybox/downloads/detail?name=jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.zip) and found the following difference which solves the issue:

```
content.find('iframe').attr('src', isIE6 && /^https/i.test(window.location.href || '') ? 'javascript:void(false)' : 'about:blank');
```

where `isIE6` evaluates to:

```
isIE6 = $.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 7 && !window.XMLHttpRequest,
```

This snippet should be executed before removing the `iframe` from the DOM.

Comment: Mighty fine detective work there sompylasar. In fact rather than updating my answer, you should probably have submitted that as a new answer so you could get the upvote credit you deserve for it.

Answer (score 8):

The problem was fixed when I removed the SRC attribute from the iframe and I added onOpen event to jQuery's dialog:

```
open: function()
  {
    document.getElementById("mainFrame").src = "/login.aspx";
  }
```

Comment: Fancybox creates the iframe on the fly. I don't know how I could work this in to the process.

Comment: You can use this approach with Fanybox using the `onComplete` event.

Answer (score 3):

I had the EXACT same issue, but the cause of mine was different.  I figured I'd share here in case others were in the same boat as me - especially given that it took me about 4 hours to track down...

Our main page had an iframe which ended up having its src attribute changed twice in a very short amount of time (we were actually loading the same src twice by accident - once directly in the HTML and then again on page load via JavaScript). I'm not sure why Internet Explorer 9 chokes, but I'm guessing that the frame was partially through initializing its scripts when the src was set again, putting the JavaScript engine into an unhappy state. Either way I'm glad I found it, since we shouldn't have been loading the frame twice!

However, the real reason why Internet Explorer 9 died so bad is a mystery.

Answer (score 2):

This is a related issue:
[IE9 throws exceptions when loading scripts in iframe. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389261/ie9-throws-exceptions-when-loading-scripts-in-iframe-why)

There seems to be some real issue in Internet Explorer with native global objects such as 'Function' and 'Object' being undefined in some circumstances when scripts are loaded early (in the head section) of an iframe...

I placed a bounty on that other question to get some more attention to it.

From experience I know this issue also exists in IE8, but it was more rare there it seems. Looks like in IE9 it has gotten worse...