# JQuery + Fancybox + Iframe + IE9 = *boom*?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, fancybox

As one can see in the Title:

I try to pop up an iframe via fancybox, and set the src that moment,
in IE9 (only!) I get many JS-errors (starting with "Array undefined" inside jquery.js)

One can see the failing Page here:
http://ib.atm.co.at/a313/Foo.aspx

Simply scroll down and click "in den Warenkorb" (=add to cart) while using IE9.

Any ideas?

Comment: what version of jQuery? what version of fancybox?

Comment: Could be one of these issues:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389261/ie9-throws-exceptions-when-loading-scripts-in-iframe-why

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528946/error-in-internet-explorer-9-not-earlier-versions-or-other-browsers-when-incl

Comment: @invertedSpear : jQuery is v1.7.2 and fancybox is v1.3.4. @santa : Your site works fine on IE7 some most likely is the bug pointed out in the link above. Why do you want to use inline iframes? Wouldn't be better to link to the page directly and use the `"type":"iframe"` fancybox API option?

Comment: @JFK : no? it should be jQuery 1.8.1, yes i know that it only fails in IE9, and I'm going to try the "type":"iframe" now...

Comment: @santa : as far as I can tell, you are loading jQuery v1.7.2 http://ib.atm.co.at/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js